# Parse.com android SDK Associate user with installation

Tags: parse-platform

Can anyone give me an example of how associate the current user with the installation son I can send push notifications to a single user associated with  an installation.

I'm using android SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Associate the device with a user
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("user",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: what would be the best moment to do this? after the user signup?

Comment: @JoseManuelOjeda I have had some issues putting it there, so I would put it on the first page the user sees after sign up/login. If this works for you, please mark as correct.